# Optionally use decorators on class methods

Tags: python, oop, decorator, python-decorators

Im new to Python, and im building a wrapper for an api. I would want to let the user decide if he/she wants to use a decorator on methods I expose from my module.

For example:

```
# create a new instance
api = MyApi()

# return a simple json response with all the data related to a timetable
print api.time_table
```

Now the user has all the data, and can do whatever he/she wants. I would want to add some kind of 'convenience' methods, for example; to let the user get a small part of the json instead of the whole big json response.

My idea was to use pythons decorators for this. Optionally my goal whould be something like this:

```
# use the method and get al the data
print api.time_table

# Optionally, get a specific part, just the shows part. (PSEUDO CODE BELOW)
@shows
print api.time_table
```

Naturally, thats not how decorators work, but is there a way to optionally use a decorator on a existing class method, or does the decorator always have to be wrapping the original method?

So what is the most Pythonic way here? I really would like to use decorator, but if thats a bad idea here, im fine with just creating more 'convenience' methods inside my `Api` class.

Comment: You can only use decorators on functions and classes, not on anything else (such as `print` statements). You'd extend your API to give the user more options instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, so theres no way of using decorators on EXISTING functions? In this case ill have to go with more class methods. Maybe ill come up with something handy using lambdas.

Comment: Sure you can use decorators too; decorators are *just functions*; `@foo` applied to `bar` is *exactly* the same as `bar = foo(bar)`; replacing `bar` with the return value of `foo` when called with `bar` as argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are to add more methods to your API or to provide the user with utility functions instead:

```
from yourmodule import MyAPI

api = MyAPI

filtered_timetable = api.filter_on(something)
```

or

```
from yourmodule import MyAPI, filter_timetable

api = MyAPI

filtered_timetable = filter_timetable(api.time_table, something)
```

Remember that decorators are just callables; the syntax:

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

`foo()` is called, and the return value replaces the decorated object. Usually you use functions for decorators, but nothing says you have to use those functions *only* as decorators.

`filter_timetable` could be such a decorator; if you have a usecase for using it as both.