# how to manipulate value of different instance attributes with same method

Tags: python, class, oop, python-decorators

I have a class that, through different methods, creates values for 2 different attributes. I would then like to manipulate those attribute values, if required, via another instance method.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.b = None
        pass

    def make_a(self, a):
        // put 'a' through some process
        self.a = a
        return self

    def make_b(self, b):
        // put 'b' through some process
        self.b = b
        return self

    def change_attr(self):
        // some change
```

I would like to be able to call `change_attr` on `make_a` or `make_b` to change the value of either `a` or `b` as required. Something like `Test().make_a(3).change_attr()` ... then access `a` on the instance after the fact.

BUT I don't know how to setup `change_attr` or the class in general so that it 'knows' what instance method was just called before it.

To call `change_attr` on the other methods, I have those methods return self, but then `change_attr` can't know what attribute to change.

A decorator feels appropriate, but it would need to be toggled on and off and I have only seen examples of this as a classmethod (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393287/how-to-make-decorators-optionally-turn-on-or-off)). Once I start trying to pass around `self` the idea breaks down.

I am wondering if a decorator is the right approach here. Or if perhaps I can somehow call an instance method *on an instance attribute* (doubt possible)...

```
test = Test()
test.make_a(5)
test.a.change_attr()
```

Or if `change_attr` can somehow be told what method was called before (also doubt possible).

For now I have a somewhat clunky approach where a parameter is passed to `change_attr` that tells the method which attribute to change.

```
def change_attr(self, attr_to_change):
    if attr_to_change == 'a':
        // make change to a
    elif attr_to_change == 'b':
        // make change to b
```

I appreciate any input!

Comment: right but how can I make `another_method` aware of `some_method` called before it?

Comment: Your method could create a flag that tells `another_method` what attribute to modify. Honestly, this sounds like a lot of work for practically no gain.

Comment: oh i've definitely invested too much time in trying to find a solution like this for practical purposes but there's learning to be done here as well