# Delay between different function calls

Tags: python

I have a question about adding delay after calling various functions.

Let's say I've function like:

```
def my_func1():
    print("Function 1")

def my_func2():
    print("Function 2")

def my_func3():
    print("Function 3")
```

Currently I've added delay between invoking them like below:

```
delay = 1
my_func1()
time.sleep(delay)
my_func2()
time.sleep(delay)
my_func3()
time.sleep(delay)
```

As you can see I needed a few times `time.sleep`, which I would like to avoid.
Using decorator is also not an option, since it might be that I would like to avoid delay when calling one of this function not in a group.

Do you have any tip how to beautify this?

Comment: It works, it is simple and readable. What's the problem?

Comment: @GhostOps Why `and`? It will lead all kinds of unexpected bugs when the function returns a falsy value (such as the ones in the question).

Comment: It looks like you already have the perfect solution to your problem: use `time.sleep`. Can you explain why you think that's not a good solution to your problem?

Comment: Would writing a wrapper like `def sleep_some(): time.sleep(delay)` help? Is the problem in repeating the call together with the delay? It's hard to figure out what your issue is, the code looks perfectly fine, and it's clear what it does, why would you want to change this?

Comment: @KlausD. This is only an example. The project I'm working on requires about 20 functions to be performed with a delay. I just don't want to repeat sleep instruction 20 times.

Comment: @TannerSwett see my upper comment

Comment: @Frax No, it wouldn't. As mentioned, delay should be optional.
For reason, look at my upper comment.

Comment: Hi @Mateusz , have you seen my answer, I posted my answer when you posted your question, but I didn't get any response nor feedbacks from you. Please give me some feedbacks. Cheers.

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam thx for your answer, it's quite nice solution, but in the end optional decorator proposed below is what i need:)

Comment: @Mateusz  Good Luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested this based on "How to Make Decorators Optionally Turn On Or Off" ([How to Make Decorators Optionally Turn On Or Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393287/how-to-make-decorators-optionally-turn-on-or-off))

```
from time import sleep

def funcdelay(func):
    def inner():
        func()
        print('inner')
        sleep(1)           
    inner.nodelay = func
    return inner 

@funcdelay
def my_func1():
    print("Function 1")

@funcdelay
def my_func2():
    print("Function 2")

@funcdelay
def my_func3():
    print("Function 3")
my_func1()
my_func2()
my_func3()
my_func1.nodelay()
my_func2.nodelay()
my_func3.nodelay()
```

Output:

```
Function 1
inner
Function 2
inner
Function 3
inner
Function 1
Function 2
Function 3
```

You can see that it can bypass the delay.

Answer (score 7):

You can define something like this:

```
def delay_it(delay, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    return_value = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

then

```
a = delay_it(1, my_func1, "arg1", arg2="arg2")
b = delay_it(1, my_func2, "arg3")
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I know what you mean but you could try:

```
functions = [my_func1, my_func2, my_func3]
for func in functions:
    func()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good way to handle delay in a function; because each function should do only one thing.
**Dont't do this:**

```py
def my_func(delay):
    # do stuff
    if delay>0:
       time.sleep(delay)
```

---

Try to make a delay handler function and put suitable delay after each function you pass to it.
**Try this:**

```py
def delay_handler(functions_list,inputs_list,delay_list):
    for function,cur_input,delay in zip(functions_list,inputs_list,delay_list):
        function(*cur_input)  
        time.sleep(delay)
```

**Tip 1:** Zip will iterate throw each list (any iterable) simultaneously; first elements in `inputs_list` and `delay_list` are for first function in `function_list` and etc.
**Tip 2:** The '*' behind a list will unpack it.